# Winsock looping until host comes online

Tags: c++, winsock

I have a client that basically wants to (from time-to-time) connect to a remote host send some messages and disconnect. But the host might not always be available. How do I set up a loop that does something like (preferably avoiding some constant cpu-time-consuming loops):

> **Attempt_Send_Data(DATA data)**
>
> ---
>
> Is the host online? **No**: Check again **Yes**: Connect, Transmit this data
> , Disconnect, return

(I am using C++ , WinSock2 and the TCP protocol)

Comment: loop over a variable called "managed_to_do_the_voodoo", which is set to false and keep on trying to connect to specific host/port with 30 second time-out. When you are successful, send the data and switch the variable to true.

Comment: I would appreciate it if you could enlighten me with the actual methods, thank you!

Comment: I bet that you would, but I don't do work for other people, especially when it's matter of googling about it.

Answer (score 0):

On a totally unrelated note, but since I was working on it when you deleted your other question, I will post it here, and deleted as soon as you have had the time to take a look at it.

For other readers, yes, this is off-topic for this question, but maybe we need a messaging system of some sort.

for starters, refactor your `getInterSection`:

```
# This return 2, 3 or 4 items, depending on the position
def getInterSection(x,y,grid):
    intersections = []
    if y > 0:
        intersections.append((x, y - 1))
    if y < grid[1] - 1:
        intersections.append((x, y + 1))
    if x > 0:
        intersections.append((x - 1, y))
    if x < grid[0] - 1:
        intersections.append((x + 1, y))
    return intersections
```

Use like so:

```
intersect = getInterSection(x,y,grid)
# This is a uniform choice, therefore probability is as expected 1/2, 1/3 or 1/4
x,y=random.choice(intersect)
```

Comment: Thank you! I removed the question since it no longer made sense since I didn't follow the question properly by going diagonally. But will update my code now thanks for the update!

Comment: Also, I did a few tests, and the formula you gave for the mean number of steps is not correctly applied. I tested with going to (14,0) and to (7,7), which have an identical number of min steps, and the mean number of actual steps vary from 200 (first case) and 290 (second case). I think it has to do with the fact that in the second case each step actually contributes for only `sqrt(2)/2` instead of 1. Possibly something to do with the direction from origin to destination.